# How to import TokenExpiredError thrown by jsonwebtoken's verify?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jwt

I'd like to check whether the type of an `Error` is `TokenExpiredError` throws by the `jwt.verify` function of the `jsonwebtoken` library using Typescript's `instanceof`, e.g.

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

function someFunction() {
    try {
        return jwt.verify(token, key);
    }catch(err) {
        if(err instanceof TokenExpiredError) {
            return attemptRenewal()
        }
        throw err
    }
}
```

How can I import the symbol `TokenExpiredError`?

I don't find any documentation about this important class and the only intuitive that comes to my mind

```
import { jwt, TokenExpiredError } from "jsonwebtoken";
```

causes `jwt` to be `undefined`.

I'm aware of workaround like performing string comparison with the class name, but I'd like to produce clean code.

I'm using `jsonwebtoken` 8.5.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`jsonwebtoken` export a default object like: [source](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/index.js)

```
module.exports = {
  decode: require('./decode'),
  verify: require('./verify'),
  sign: require('./sign'),
  JsonWebTokenError: require('./lib/JsonWebTokenError'),
  NotBeforeError: require('./lib/NotBeforeError'),
  TokenExpiredError: require('./lib/TokenExpiredError'),
};
```

This mean, when you use `import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";` syntax, `jwt` will come to a object with all properties of default export.

You can not use `import { jwt, TokenExpiredError } from "jsonwebtoken";`, because in default export object, we do not have `jwt` property,

If you want to import `TokenExpiredError` and the default object, you can follow a syntax like: `import jwt, {TokenExpiredError} from "jsonwebtoken";` , then `jwt` still is default export object, and you have `TokenExpiredError` object (`jwt.TokenExpiredError` and `TokenExpiredError` is the same).

If you just want to use `verify` function and `TokenExpiredError`, the import line will come to: `import {TokenExpiredError, verify} from "jsonwebtoken";`, then you function will be like:

```
import {TokenExpiredError, verify} from "jsonwebtoken";

function someFunction() {
  try {
    return verify(token, key);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof TokenExpiredError) {
      return attemptRenewal()
    }
    throw err
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

i had the same inquiry, but after a quick search and test, below should work

```
import * as jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

function someFunction() {
    try {
        return jwt.verify(token, key);
    }catch(err) {
        if(err instanceof jwt.TokenExpiredError) {
            return attemptRenewal()
        }
        throw err
    }
}
```

`TokenExpiredError` has been already imported as part of the jwt.

Answer (score 0):

```
import jwt, {TokenExpiredError} from "jsonwebtoken";
```